# Taking multiple pictures fast and uploading them in android

Tags: android, image, video, camera, uploading

I am developing a security application which records a series of images and then uploads them to a server. I have a few problems through.

1 My picture capture code is working, but it is very slow, I have the takePicture() method inside onPictureCallback to take another picture, however I only get a couple pictures a minute, however if on the system camera app by clicking the shutter button very fast you can take pictures at a much higher speed, I thought my way would be the fastest possible, do you know how I can increase the the speed?

2 My upload code is also working, however im not sure how to create a upload que from the pictures taken. I have tried using a database, however the file comes back static and I can't put the then static URI into the database as the method won't accept a static variable. I can't use a standard array as I would like to be able to resume uploading if the phone restarts.

3 Lastly im only using taking pictures as their doen't seem to be a way to access frames while recording video. Is their some sort of way, to reocord video a low framerate, pause it get a frame put that in an upload que and then carry on recording?

Im just guessing that if you pause a video your saving it somewhere temporarily and carrying on afterwards.

I would be very grateful if I can get help with any of the 3 issues.

Answer (score 0):

For problem number 2, try using a scheme that can handle concurrent connections like non-blocking sockets or something similar so that multiple images can be uploaded at once. This method would make the queueing scheme unnecessary.

If possible, I would recommend using a networking library like [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/) since it handles all of that ugly concurrent networking code for you.

Comment: Queueing seems like a very good idea when you have a mobile connection and multiple photos being taken very quickly back-to-back.